# copy and rename using batch files

Tags: batch-file

Hi I need to create a batch file that will copy the information in the batch file to a new .txt file.  Also I need to make a batch file that will rename a .txt file

Comment: And what exactly is the question?  Do you have a specific problem with these batch files that you need us to help you with?

Comment: Ya I have hardly any experience with batch files, I dont really know what commands or what to enter

Comment: In that case I'd suggest you start with a good [tutorial](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have the courtesy to search for a similar question first before posting here, like [Batch Commands to Copy, Rename then move all fail](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10527293/62576), [Rename files using batch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3919027/62576), and at least a dozen more that appear in the "Related" list to the right as you tagged your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ren` and `rename` to rename files, and `copy` to duplicate a file.

```
rename oldname newname
copy oldfile newfile
```

I am assuming you're using MS-DOS.

Comment: Another question, how would I make a loop to copy it at a certain time?